# How to display the maximum value from one column in a listbox, in a textbox on the same form

Tags: ms-access, listbox, controls

How can I select the maximum value from a column in a listbox, and display that value in a textbox on the same form?  The listbox itself is populated by a query that depends on user inputs, so its values are unknown in advance.

I could sort the listbox by value and select the first value, but it is already sorted by date on another column, for a different purpose. What I want to know is the Date on which that maximimum value occurred in column 2.

The next step is to display or all the values in column 4 which occure before that date as blank or N/A.

Comment: What mechanism selects the query that populates your listbox? You say it is based on a query dependent on user input, at the time that the user dictates the query can you use DMAX to populate the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following VBA code helpful. It scans values inside the `.Column` data for a list box named `List0`, for example...

```
2013-04-18 | 123
2013-04-17 | 77
2013-04-16 | 345
2013-04-15 | 34
```

...finds the date (first column) corresponding to the maximum value in the second column of the list box, and puts that date into a text box named `Text3`. Note that the `CompareNumeric` flag controls whether the comparison is string-based ("77" would win), or number-based (345 would win).

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Const DateCol = 0  '' column numbers start with 0
Const MaxCol = 1  '' second column has column index of 1
Const CompareNumeric = True  '' convert strings to numbers for finding maximum

Dim RowIdx As Long, MaxItem As Variant, MaxIdx As Long, CurrItem As Variant, NewMaxFound As Boolean

MaxIdx = -1
MaxItem = Null
For RowIdx = 0 To Me.List0.ListCount - 1
    CurrItem = Me.List0.Column(MaxCol, RowIdx)
    If CompareNumeric Then
        CurrItem = Val(CurrItem)
    End If

    If IsNull(MaxItem) Then
        NewMaxFound = True  '' first one
    Else
        NewMaxFound = (CurrItem > MaxItem)
    End If
    If NewMaxFound Then
        MaxItem = CurrItem
        MaxIdx = RowIdx
    End If
Next
If MaxIdx >= 0 Then
    Me.Text3.Value = Me.List0.Column(DateCol, MaxIdx)
End If
End Sub
```